# what is the Installer default path in the start menu?

Tags: inno-setup

I have created an installer using the Inno-setup. Once the installation is complete the application goes and sits in the place "start ->programs -> myappname ".

Here even though I have given different path like "c:\Program files\XXXX\myappname" while installation , it is showing in the start menu as "programs->myappname" instead of "programs\XXXX\myappname"

Is there any default path the Inno setup is maintaining? How to change this display in the start menu ?

Comment: While installing if the user selects a different path? Can't I get the path in runtime and update the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at setting the `DefaultGroupName` directive in the `[Setup]` section ?

Description:

> The value of this directive is used for the default Start Menu folder
>   name on the Select Start Menu Folder page of the wizard. If this
>   directive is blank or isn't specified, it will use "(Default)" for the
>   name.

To answer your question in the comment ... do you want the users to be able to change the installation path ? If not, add `DisableDirPage=yes` line to the `[Setup]` section.

Comment: Also refer to the documentation on the `[Setup]` section: http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupsection

Comment: I got the concept. Incase if the user has been provided to install the application in the place he needed, then is it possible to retrieve the path in runtime and update the start menu as per the folder selected.

Comment: The `{app}` constant is "The application directory, which the user selects on the Select Destination Location page of the wizard." Here's the link to it (and the others): http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts

Comment: DefaultGroupName={#MyAppContact}\{#MyAppName} changed this variable to reflect the path